# Como comunicar abas com uma extensão/add-on e armazenar as variáveis?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão, firefox-extensão

Quero poder comunicar abas com uma extensão e ir armazenando valores em variáveis e compartilhar estes valores entre abas, como posso fazer isto?

> **Nota:** isto é uma pergunta tutorial, leia mais em:
>
> - [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) <sup>Help</sup>
> - [Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/37/3635) <sup>faq</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Nota:** link com exemplo completo e funcional para usar/testar:
>
> - https://github.com/brcontainer/tutorial-add-on-stack-overflow

Para que algo fique em execução você deve usar o `background.js` na sua extensão e armazenar os valores, ou para ser mais preciso:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
```

O *background* funciona como um servidor **back-end**, ele fica rodando constantemente, mesmo sem abas abertas de um site especificado no `manifest.json`

Todas abas geradas e que suas páginas sejam especificadas no manifest.json podem acessar a mesma execução do `background.js`, pois só existirá uma, ou seja para cada extensão é gerado um processo que fica executando o `background.js`.

Tendo entendido isto vamos paras as abas, quando a extensão inicia (logo no arranque do navegador) você poderá se comunicar com ela, cada aba/janela nova aberta poderá se comunicar com o `background.js`

Para comunicar uma aba com o background será necessário usar:

- `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

E para receber a requisição no background será necessário usar:

- `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`

No entanto para isto será necessário injetar scripts nas páginas especificadas no `content_scripts.matches`, por exemplo, crie um script chamado `inject.js` na pasta do add-on e no `manifest.json` deixe algo como isto:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "*://superuser.com/*",
        "*://serverfault.com/*",
        "*://stackoverflow.com/*",

        "*://*.superuser.com/*",
        "*://*.serverfault.com/*",
        "*://*.stackoverflow.com/*"
    ],
    "js": [
        "inject.js"
    ]
}],
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

No exemplo acima defini que o `inject.js` será adicionado as seguintes páginas:

- irá ser injetado em qualquer página de superuser.com (podendo ser adicionado a um sub-dominio)
- irá ser injetado em qualquer página de serverfault.com (podendo ser adicionado a um sub-dominio)
- irá ser injetado em qualquer página de stackoverflow.com (podendo ser adicionado a um sub-dominio)

Agora no conteúdo do `background.js` adicione isto:

```
(function (browser) {

    var valorX = 0, valorY = 0, valorZ = 0; //Os valores vão ficar salvos nessas variaveis

    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendFeedback) {

        switch (request) {
            case "acaoX":
                sendFeedback("Foi chamado a ação X");
                valorX++; //Incrementa em valorX toda vez que chamar acaoZ
                break;

            case "acaoY":
                sendFeedback("Foi chamado a ação Y");
                valorY++; //Incrementa em valorY toda vez que chamar acaoZ
                break;

            case "acaoZ":
                sendFeedback("Foi chamado a ação Z");
                valorZ++; //Incrementa em valorZ toda vez que chamar acaoZ
                break;

            //Será usado para ver na aba quantas ações de cada foram chamadas
            case "total":
                sendFeedback({
                    "x": valorX,
                    "y": valorY,
                    "z": valorZ
                });
                break;
        }
    });
})(browser||chrome); //compatibilidade para firefox e chrome
```

Agora no `inject.js` adicione isto:

```
(function (browser) {
    function requisitarAcao(acao, callback) {
        if (browser && browser.runtime && browser.runtime.sendMessage) {
            browser.runtime.sendMessage(acao, function (response) {
                callback(response);
            });
        }
    }

    var gerado = false;

    //Cria 3 botões no final da página
    function gerarBotoes() {
        if (gerado) return; //Impede que gere mais de uma vez

        gerado = true;

        var btnX = document.createElement("button"),
            btnY = document.createElement("button"),
            btnZ = document.createElement("button"),
            btnMostrarTotal = document.createElement("button");

        btnX.textContent = "Chama ação X";
        btnY.textContent = "Chama ação Y";
        btnZ.textContent = "Chama ação Z";
        btnMostrarTotal.textContent = "Total";

        btnX.onclick = function () {
            requisitarAcao("acaoX", function (resposta) {
                alert(resposta);
            });
        };

        btnY.onclick = function () {
            requisitarAcao("acaoY", function (resposta) {
                alert(resposta);
            });
        };

        btnZ.onclick = function () {
            requisitarAcao("acaoZ", function (resposta) {
                alert(resposta);
            });
        };

        btnMostrarTotal.onclick = function () {
            requisitarAcao("total", function (resposta) {
                var totalResposta = [
                    "vezes que chamou a ação X:" + resposta.x,
                    "vezes que chamou a ação Y:" + resposta.y,
                    "vezes que chamou a ação Z:" + resposta.z
                ];

                alert(totalResposta.join("\n"));
            });
        };

        document.body.appendChild(btnX);
        document.body.appendChild(btnY);
        document.body.appendChild(btnZ);
        document.body.appendChild(btnMostrarTotal);
    }

    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/.test(document.readyState)) {
        gerarBotoes();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", gerarBotoes);
        window.addEventListener("load", gerarBotoes);
    }
})(chrome||browser); //compatibilidade para firefox e chrome
```

> Nota: Criei 3 botões, mas é só pra exemplificar, você pode ser qualquer coisa, até um loop com `setTimeout`, depende do que deseja).

Pronto tendo salvo tudo, carregue a extensão pelo modo desenvolvedor e abra qualquer um dos sites citados acima no `content_scripts.matches`, irá notar isto no rodapé deles:

[image: botões gerados pelo add-on nos sites definidos no manifest.json]

Então clique quantas vezes quiser nos 3 primeiros, eles vão sendo somados e por fim, quando se cansar clique no botão chamado <kbd>Total</kbd>, ele vai exibir o total de *hits* dos 3 links acima

Agora abra uma aba nova de um site diferente do que abriu antes, se abriu o `pt.stackoverflow.com` agora abra o `superuser.com`, mas ao invés de clicar nos botões de ação, clique no <kbd>Total</kbd> diretamente:

[image: resultado]

No meu caso eu só tinha clicado uma vez em X e uma em Z, mas na nova aba os valores se mantiveram.

Pronto, desta maneira todas abas tem os mesmo dados e você continua de onde parou, no entanto é importante saber que se fechar o navegador é o mesmo que finalizar um servidor, você vai finalizar o background.js e portanto na próxima vezes que iniciar o navegador o `background.js` irá iniciar do zero, se desejar manter os dados salvos será necessário usar algo como `localStorage`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage